# Typescript error Property x does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to `Typescript`. Using Nextjs, I have a basic component I would like to typecheck, however I am getting the error. How can i typecheck my array of objects?

```
ERROR in C:/Users/Matt/sites/shell/pages/index.tsx(22,4):
22:4 Property 'swc' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
    20 |        render() {
    21 |                const {
    22 |                        swc: { results }
       |                        ^
    23 |                } = this.props;

type Props = {
    results: Array<any>;
};
```

Component:

```
interface Props {
    swc: Object;
    results: Array<any>;
}
class swc extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const res = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/");
        const swc = await res.json();

        return {
            swc
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {
            swc: { results }
        } = this.props;

        return results.map(swc => (
            <Layout>
    ...
            </Layout>
        ));
    }
}

export default swc;
```

this.props:

```
 { swc:
   { count: 87,
     next: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2',
     previous: null,
     results:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  url:
   { query: [Getter],
     pathname: [Getter],
     asPath: [Getter],
     back: [Function: back],
     push: [Function: push],
     pushTo: [Function: pushTo],
     replace: [Function: replace],
     replaceTo: [Function: replaceTo] } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the `props` object defined inside the `swc` class, no need to destruct the class itself.

> You're essentially **trying to access `swc.props.swc.results`** when you should be **accessing `swc.props.results` instead**

---

In general though, this seems like an incorrect component set up and I'm confused by your `props` definition as you seem to be passing `results` prop and then `swc` to props, which is the component itself (?)

It's hard for me to answer this without further detail, but I'd imagine you'd want to do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

type Props = {
   results: any[], // < try to be more specific than any[]
}

// React Components should per convention start with Uppercase
class Swc extends Component<Props, {}> {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
     const res = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
     const json = await res.json()
     return { json.swc.results }
  }

  render() {
     const { results } = this.props
     // React components should always return a singular tag 
     // (eg. div, React.Fragment, but not array of <Layout>
     const renderResults = results && results.map(result => (
         <Layout>
            {result}
         </Layout>
     ))

      return (
        <>
          {renderResults}
        </>
      )

  }
}

export default Swc
```

Comment: Done that but get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - results in empty

Comment: Okay I'm slightly more confused with your edit after my answer. Why do you have `Props` as `results` and `swc` when `swc` is also the component itself.

This smells more like incorrect component set-up to me, thing is I can't really answer your question without you providing some expected behaviour / description of what it does

Comment: I am new to typescript  Im learning as I go - I just want to get a basic example working where I can check the prop type. I want to display a list of star wars characters and check the props are an array of objects

Comment: thanks that's what i'm after, but `this.props` was wrong. I have edited the question

Comment: @Bomber prob try  `const json = await res.json()` `return { json.swc.results }`  inside `getInitialProps` and the rest of my edited answer should work